# Atom: Go-To-Definition shortcut for PHP

Tags: php, atom-editor

Is there any good "go-to-definition" method for Atom? I tried [go-to-definiton](https://atom.io/packages/goto-definition) package, but it needs 2-10sec to to go to the definition. (In Sublime text it's a lot more quicker.

Answer (score 0):

There is a topic on the atom discuss site about this subject. Since the last 22 days (4/08/2016) there is no native feature to go-to-definition.

Topic link: [Is there a simple go-to-definition](https://discuss.atom.io/t/is-there-a-simple-go-to-definition/11809/14)

But there is another package that you can try to use.

There's [goto](https://atom.io/packages/goto) package which replaces symbols-view (which can be disabled); no ctags needed